# Control access to admin console for glassfish

Tags: glassfish

Is it possible to add multiple addresses in admin-listener in order to grant access for a specific people ?

[image: admin listener]

Instead of "0.0.0.0" (default address) i added "192.168.56.10".

So can i add another address to "192.168.56.10"?

Comment: You are configuring the address on which the server listens, not _who_ is able to connect. If you use your example, the server will only listen on 192.168.56.10, and not on the default 0.0.0.0. Still every client on the same network will be able to connect to 192.168.56.10. I don't recall any option to configure what you want. Try adding specific firewall rules instead.

Comment: maybe check http://serverfault.com/questions/238074/glassfish-v2-access-control-by-ip

Comment: @Lenniey thanks a lot for the link, it works, in `configurations -> Virtual Servers -> __asadmin` i added the properties `allowRemoteAddress` `denyRemoteAddress` with the addresses i needed and it works, thanks a lot ^_^